# python cache false - not working

Tags: python-3.x, caching

I'm working with an Bombay Stock Exchange API: 
http://nsetools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#getting-a-stock-quote

I'm getting correct response when I try the following code:

```
q = (nse.get_quote('infy'))
```

I've automated the above query every 5 seconds. The 'infy' value is expected to be changed everytime it is loaded. But it remains the same. The code isn't loading everytime - but it is captured from cache.

The website has a note:

> After the first time use, this api returns the cached value. To avoid
>   caching use get_stock_codes(cached=False)

So when I try the code as this:

```
q = (nse.get_quote('infy',cached=False))
```

I get an error:

> Error: TypeError: get_quote() got an unexpected keyword argument
>   'Cached'

Can someone explain what is wrong?

Comment: `get_quote` doesn't have a `chached` option. It's not the same as `get_stock_codes`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the `infy` value is expected to change? The quote you're expecting? the parameter itself? Why is it expected to change every time it loads?

Comment: Hi Kabanus, 

infy is the code for stock company infosys, India. 

The nse.get_quote('infy') code gets the latest price of the stock. So every time I manually load it, it shows the current stock price of it. But if I automate it, it doesn't show the updated value but the same value it loaded at first.

Comment: Why do you think the stock price should change so fast. go here: http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/computers-software/infosys/IT. Hit refresh every 5 seconds - see if the stock price changes. There is no evidence in the `nse` source code that it's using a cached valued for `get_quote`, I think it's just not changing as fast as you expect.

Comment: I tried launching the app manually and it changed from time to time. But if I leave the app for auto refresh, it returns the same result again and again. For a long time. 

However, I will try again tomorrow when the market is open. Thanks Kabanus.